# Function to get custom taxonomy page URL in WordPress posts page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

How can I get custom taxonomy page URL in PHP on WordPress?
I have created custom taxonomy name "developer" for posts core on WordPress, this is the URL https://check1.site/developer/Fingersoft/.
Each post has one or 2 developers tag assigned.
Now I want to call this URL in PHP, but I am not sure what code should I use to echo this URL in posts

I tried [`get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) but it returns current post URL not the developer URL

Comment: Some feedback on the answers below will be appreciated, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the URL(s) of each custom taxonomy **term(s)**, *but not the URL of your custom taxonomy itself*. For that, you will simply use the function [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) WordPress function like in the example below:

```
$taxonomy = 'developer'; // Your custom taxonomy slug

// Get your custom taxonomy term(s) from an existing post ID
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
$html = ''; // initializing variable for output

// Loop through each custom taxonomy WP_Term in the current post 
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
   $term_link =  get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); // Get the term link
   
   $html .= '<li><a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; // formatting for output
}

echo '<ul>' . $output . '</ul></pre>'; // Displaying formatted output
```

This will display a list of the "Developer" linked term(s) for the current post.

Answer (score -1):

The function you are looking for is `get_term_link`. It takes either a term object, ID or slug and a taxonomy name and returns a URL to the term landing page.

```
$terms = get_terms('developer');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'developer').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```